# error:cannot find module openstudio how to specify openstudio package or path for nodejs

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, npm, npm-install

I want to call `open-studio` from `node.js`. I have cloned source code from  and loaded all npm packages required but after that I am getting error. Cannot find module openstudio. I have installed openstudio but my question is: How to specify the path for `nodejs` in windows machine eclipse environment?

Comment: Can you post what you already have ?

Comment: i have openstudio and nodejs and npm pacakges also installed like connect tail etc.. but openstudio package not available on npm so how we can link openstudio to nodejs.. while i am executing nodejs scripts from github getting error can not find module openstudio...